# Firebase, Could Messaging - add FCM feature doesn't see the added "google-services" classpath

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-cloud-messaging, build.gradle

Good evening!

I'm new to Firebase and currently I'm trying to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging.
I've connected Firebase but after I confirm "Add FCM to your app" dialog and sync finishes successfully the app doesn't get added and the button "Add FCM to your app" stays inactive.

The change that needs to be done is already added to the root build.gradle file of the project (on the screenshot):

```
build.gradle (project-level)

    Add rules to include the Google Services Gradle plugin:
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
```

[image]

I expect that the "Add FCM to your app" button will also change to a checkmark if the operation has ended successfully.

What else can I do to add FCM or are there any ways that I can troubleshoot the issue? I've already checked multiple times everything leading to this point and can't see a mistake.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried everything - restarting Android Studio, writing down the class by hand, starting the "add FCM" process over and over again and in the what helped to finish the synchronization in my case - commenting the line and allowing the service to generate it again.

[image]